# Flask apache2 server structure

Tags: python, flask

today i finally uploaded my flask project to a apache server, and it is working! But there is one problem

my server gets launched by this .wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/webApp/")

from webApp import app as application
```

But there is now one problem for me.

My main python code has global variables named "temp_faq".
There is also a "def setup" data which gets called whenever the server starts

Now the .wsgi code just imports the flask-app without my data-variables.

Any one knows how i could change this?

My structure is like this

**init**.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_data()
    db.create_all()
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

the setup_data() definition changes the global variables in the **init**.py and every other function could use them.

I hope you understand my problem.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/) to see the steps for wsgi.

[This link](https://pythonprogramming.net/basic-flask-website-tutorial/) is also helpful.

The block `if __name__ == '__main__':` won't be executed.

In the `<yourapplication>.wsgi` file, you need to give the application instance or variable which will be used & not in the `__init__.py` file.